# Integrating Grafana with keycloak,How to manage user access?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, grafana

**problem**

integrating grafana with keycloak
a realm: zzy, two users: daicy,sscc
when I hit the Grafana URL, it is redirecting to keycloak and authenticating the user.

result:
daicy,sscc all can pass

hope:
sscc can pass, daicy failed.

What do I need to do to get the hope result.

**Methods i tried**
i read the keycloak document [user based policy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_policy_overview)

then i follow the document, but failed, all users can authenticated.

Here are my setting up for authorization:

[user policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Etu5.png)

[user daicy policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwVRs.png)

[user sscc policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqLwM.png)

[resource permision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj1MG.png)

Anyone managed to go through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity provider is for authentication (not for authorization). If you want to use authorization services, then they must be supported on the Service Provider side (Grafana in your case).

Unfortunately, Grafana doesn't support Keycloak authorization services out of the box. It supports only role based authorization (`role_attribute_path`). Unfortunately, you can't deny access for authenticated users on the Grafana side, because they will always have at least Viewer role - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/23218

Answer (score 0):

Grafana works well with Keycloak.
Please create a mapper within your keycloak grafana client in order to receive roles into json userinfo

Please see the following sample mapper

[image]

And your /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

```
login_attribute_path = preferred_username    
role_attribute_path = contains(roles[], 'admin') && 'Admin' || contains(roles[], 'editor') && 'Editor' || 'Viewer'
```

At the end of the configuration restart grafana service and logout of all keycloak sessions.